# titlesec formatting

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
\titlespacing{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}

\begin{document}


\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...
```

how do I do this using titlesec package what do I put in:

```
 \titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
```

and:

```
  \titlespacing{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some thing like this?

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\filcenter\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
    {20pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.7in}{20pt}
```

I didn't understand `double space` to some extent. I have used `20pt`, but you may use `\baselineskip` instead of `20pt`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\filcenter\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
    {20pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.7in}{20pt}

\begin{document}


\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante.
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...
\end{document}
```

[image]