# How to control spacing in a title with titlesec while using float

Tags: spacing, floats, titlesec

After editing the title of a chapter with package `titlesec` and the command `\titleformat`, I realized that the spacing between lines is changed when a figure environment using the option `[H]` from the package `float` is used.
I can replace `[H]` for `[h]` to let LaTeX displace the figure wherever it finds better, or add a `\clearpage` to return the line spacing in the title back to the original one.

I like to use `[H]` while editing to avoid LaTeX replacing figures and I still don't know the final version of the text, or even the figure size.  So:

1. What should I do to avoid the undesired line spacing in title?
2. What are good methods to control the line spacing of the text when floats are floating around?

I checked [titlesec formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198468/titlesec-formatting) but I didn't seem to have any effect.

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace{-2.5cm}\normalfont\Large\filcenter\bfseries} % \sffamily
{\titlerule[1.5pt]%
  \vspace{5pt}%
  {\Huge{\chaptertitlename} {\thechapter}}
}
{2pt}
{\titlerule
  \vspace{2pt}%
  \Huge\bfseries
  \vspace{5pt}
}
[{\titlerule[1.5pt]}\vspace{-20pt}]
% I don't know how and if titlespacing would help
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{5pt}{0.7in}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{title}

\lipsum[1-4]

% \clearpage
\begin{figure}[H] % [h]
  \includegraphics[width = 0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the figures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding \raggedbottom to your preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `[H]`. Anyway, the issue can be somewhat cured by setting `\parskip` to zero inside the chapter title.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\normalfont\Large\filcenter\bfseries} % \sffamily
{\titlerule[1.5pt]%
  \vspace{5pt}%
  {\Huge{\chaptertitlename} {\thechapter}}
}
{2pt}
{\titlerule
  \vspace{2pt}%
  \Huge\bfseries
  \vspace{5pt}
}
[{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]
% I don't know how and if titlespacing would help
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt} % fix the 20pt to suit

\begin{document}
\chapter{title}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[H] % [h]
  \includegraphics[width = 0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I removed the “eye-computed” negative vertical space and added the `\titlespacing` instruction to get the *precise* result.

[image]

The stretch is only between paragraphs in the text and not in the chapter title. The result is disastrous anyway, but it's caused by `[H]`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\normalfont\Large\filcenter\bfseries} % \sffamily
{\titlerule[1.5pt]%
  \vspace{5pt}%
  {\Huge{\chaptertitlename} {\thechapter}}
}
{2pt}
{\titlerule
  \vspace{2pt}%
  \Huge\bfseries
  \vspace{5pt}
}
[{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]
% I don't know how and if titlespacing would help
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}% fix the 20pt to suit

\begin{document}
\chapter{title}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[!htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]